# Prevent nulling of optional foreign key when deleting parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an optional relationship between `Table A` and `Table B` where A is the parent and B is the optional child. If I have only A loaded in my DbContext SQL Server will throw me an error that I cannot delete A because of a relationship with B, this is what I want.

However if I have A and the relation to B loaded in the DbContext Entity Framework will set the relationship on B to `null` which prevents the error from SQL Server. How can I prevent Entity Framework from setting my relationship to `null` when deleting the parent A?

I want the error to happen as I want to prevent deletion of A when a relationship exists, I don't want Entity Framework to 'fix' the issue for me.

Comment: Do you want the item in `Table B`to be deleted as well? If so you could think of using `Cascading Delete` feature of EF

Comment: No, I don't want it to touch B at all

Comment: B does indeed have a reference to A, which is exactly why I want it to throw the exception and prevent the update rather than have B updated with a `null` reference.

Comment: `one-to-one` or `one-to-many`? Use fluent configuration `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`.

Comment: one-to-many, one A can have many B. I want to prevent the deletion of A when there is any B